# Cells of UITableView not getting clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm new in the world of Iphone development. I got a very strange problem with my tableView, I have made many tableViews with different data in it but it never happened ever before.

My data is been shown on tableView but it is not getting clicked. I also deleted that controller and created another one but it doesn't work there as well. Although when i create another project and make tableView it works fine. Anyone if you can help, thanks in advance.

So far i have tried to console a string in my

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

to check but it didn't console anything.

here is my code of method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

I used breakpoints and came to know that it is not even entering in didSelect method.. may be delegate is not being called. But why ? because i have declared it in (.h) file @interface simpleDataViewController : UIViewController  and also in (.m) file  _table.delegate = self; _table.dataSource =self;

Comment: Show `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code.

Comment: Did you set the table's `delegate` property?

Comment: yes i did. also connected it in my storyboard.

Comment: Provide some sample code for `cellForRowArIndexPath`. Apart from that to rectify your problem 

1.  You also need to confirm whether or not you are able to scroll through the table view cells. If you are not then, this could be possibly due to some other overlapping views in your code or may be that the tableview is not on the top hierarchy.

2. Provide the frame size values of your tableView.

Comment: Just to be clear - your delegate is setup properly and you have implemented the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. But when you tap on a cell, that method is not being called. Correct?

Comment: @maddy yes i have checked it. my method is defined plus i have declared my delegates as well

Comment: @BalramTiwari I have already posted my code of this method in my edited version of question plus yes my scroll also doesn't work here. help!

Comment: Are you sure about this **self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;**

Comment: @Arun Verify the method is actually spelled correctly. Perhaps you should copy and paste the method into your question. Also be sure you have not implemented the `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. And lastly, is the table view in edit mode? Is `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` enabled? Is `allowsSelection` enabled?

Comment: @maddy I have not implemented tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: nor it is in editable mode.

Comment: @KumarKl Let me try this.

Comment: @KumarKl it didn't make any difference, i just tried it.

Comment: @maddy should i enable allowsSelectionDuringEditing ?

Comment: @Arun Enabling `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` must be done if your table is in edit mode and you want selections to still work. Turn it on. See if it helps.

Comment: @maddy i enabled it in viewdidload method.. still no difference 

_table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: @Arun : As you accepted that the scroll doesn't works & also you are able to see the data on table cells, then the problem is not with the `tableView`. You have said that you are able to do this freshly in a new project, but not in the existing project, it means that there must be something else, probably any other view with `clearColor` is on top of your table view. Please check & confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the delegate to that tableView, if not do below

```
[yourTableView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Have you make your table view user interaction enabled??

Comment: Though asking it is meaning less still I am asking have you called `UITableViewDelegate` in header?

Comment: @TapasPal : You can conform to protocol in any file be it implementation or header.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope that, UITableView has disabled for interaction.

Add this at **ViewDidLoad**

```
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: @rmaddy : Sorry I confused. Edited to my original thought

Comment: @KumarKl : This is something what we set explicitly. By default the `userInteractionEnabled` is TRUE for UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

there is some basic thing u have to look out when u are using uitableview,

use protocol `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

after that use `@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *Mytableview;`

May be causing some problem in time of `@synthesize` , so create it unique by writing

`@synthesize  Mytableview = _Mytableview;`

after that set delegate and datasource

`[_Mytableview setdelegate:self];`

`[_Mytableview setDatasorce:self];`

.. check this if it works

Comment: I have tried everything what you said but still its firm just like an image, un-clickable

Comment: @Arun : If you have done everything & still it is not working then kindly provide code for your table creation. If that is done through storyboards then provide the screens for the attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having cellSelectionStyle set either via code or via attribute inspector.

`[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`

As long as you don't determine the cell selection style the Cell will not show any click appearance, however the click happens & `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called. So by appearance if you are feeling that cell is not clicked then set the `selectionStyle` for cell, as

`[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefaul];`

Comment: 1. i have set [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefaul];
2. i used breakpoints and came to know that it is not even entering in didSelect method.. may be delegate is not being called

Comment: If you are sure that `delegate` is not being set then why don't you set the `delegates`.

I guess you are doing it via `IBOutlet`. 
Can you provide the property declaration. If not kindly include this in your `simpleDataViewController.h` file

`@interface simpleDataViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableDataSourceDelegate>

@end`
    
and in your `simpleDataViewController.m` file please do this after initializing you tableView in `viewDidLoad` method.

`tableViewObject.delegate = self;`
`tableViewObject.datasource = self;`

Comment: I have already done all this but in spite of all this it did not work. with same source code i created another project and it worked there. It means there is nothing wrong is my procedure or code but with my project. since i couldn't find out the error so I have created another project and dropping code there.